# HTML5 WebSQL and Foreign Keys - are they supported?

Tags: html, web-sql

I know WebSQL itself is technically not supported anymore, but it seems a lot of people still use it (as I *need* to). However, I can't seem to find a definitive answer to the Foreign Key question. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8183185/717682) reference to the fact that it *isn't* permitted, but that answer is almost 3 years old (as of this writing). I have also seen other people discussing their use of foreign keys with webSQL, such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13968602/why-foreign-key-doesnt-work-in-websql) (though they indicate some browsers don't support the work around).

So, does WebSQL permit the use of Foreign Keys? Is it a simple "yes" or "no" or is it more complicated?

Answer (score 1):

All you need to confirm that is to actually open a DB connection and create tables however you want and run SQLs that fits your requirements.

Here is how you can do it with just a single line of code and then just SQLs:

Create a test.html file and places just this content in that file:

```
<script>
 var db = openDatabase('mydb', '1.0', 'my first database', 2 * 1024 * 1024);
</script>
```

Open this file in chrome(double click/drop it on chrome) and then press F12, this will open up Chrome debugger.

Go to "Resources Tab" and then select WebSQL->mydb on left hand pane, This will give you a prompt to write any SQL query. create table, insert values or any SQL that sqllite support:

http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know I could create/manipulate tables right from Chrome. I was always using it as a viewer, not a 'hands on' manipulator. I'll have to try this to see if I can make a Foreign Key constraint. Thanks for this.